# Display user entered data in the redirected page

Tags: php, database, forms, redirect, submit

I just started to familiarize myself with PHP, and what I am trying to do at the moment is when form is submitted, you get redirected to confirmation page where you will see message like:

```
Thank you John Smith for submiting folowing info:
Address: blah blah blah
Mobile phone number: blah blah blah
Landline phone number: blah blah blah
Email: blah blah blah
(where blah blah blah is data that user entered in form)
```

So here is my main code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
header("Location: form.php");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    ******
</head>

<body>
<header class="main-header">
    ***
</header>

<main id="main">
<?php
define('DB_NAME', '***');
define('DB_USER', '***');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '***');
define('DB_HOST', '***');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$forenameErr = $surnameErr = $emailErr = $sendMethodErr = "";
$forename = $surname = $address = $mobile = $landline = $email = $sendMethod = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$forename = $_POST['forename']; 
$surname   = $_POST['surname'];
$address = $_POST['postalAddress'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobileTelNo'];
$landline = $_POST['landLineTelNo'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sendMethod = $_POST['sendMethod'];
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO CT_expressedInterest (forename, surname, postalAddress, mobileTelNo, landLineTelNo, email, sendMethod) 
VALUES('$forename', '$surname', '$address', '$mobile', '$landline', '$email', '$sendMethod')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close();
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?> ">
<fieldset class="formfield"> <!--adds box around content of this element-->
    <legend>Your Details</legend>   <!--Gives title to this fieldset-->
    <p>Fields marked with * are required for form submition.</p>       
        <label for="forename">First Name:</label> 
                <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" placeholder = "Enter your First Name" tabindex="12" required /> 
        <label for="surname">Last Name(s):</label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" placeholder = "Enter your Last Name" tabindex="13" required /> 
        <label for="postalAddress">Postal Address:</label>
                <input type="text" name="postalAddress" id="postalAddress" placeholder = "Your house number, street name and postcode"tabindex="14"/> 
        <label for="mobileTelNo">Mobile Telephone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="mobileTelNo" id="mobileTelNo" placeholder = "Enter your mobile number" tabindex="19"/> 
        <label for="landLineTelNo">Landline Telephone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="landLineTelNo" id="landLineTelNo" placeholder = "Enter your landline number" tabindex="19"/>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder = "Enter your email address" tabindex="20"/> <br/>
        <p> How Would You Like To Recieve Further Information?</p>
        <label id="post">Post</label>           
            <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="Post" tabindex="34" placeholder = "please choose one" required >
        <label id="eemail">Email</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="Email" tabindex="35">
        <label id="sms">SMS Text</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sendMethod" value="SMS" tabindex="36">

    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="check" id="agree" required /> I have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy </p>
    <p> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </p>
    </fieldset>

    </form>

</main>


<footer class="main-footer">
    ***
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is what i have so far for form.php, but obviously it is not working. *(i am not sure if i need to connect to database in this file as well)*

```
echo "<p>Thank you $forename $surname</p>";
    echo "<p>We have recieved following information:</p>";   
    echo "<p>Address: $address</p>";
    echo "<p>Mobile phone number: $mobile</p>";
    echo "<p>Landline phone number: $landline</p>";
    echo "<p>Email: $email </p>";
```

Can anyone please help me to finish form.php code?
And one more thing. After I press submit button, two new records are added to my database. One with info that was entered it the form and one is completely empty. 
I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

*p.s. i an not allowed to use any jquery or ajax things.*

Comment: add the $_POST variables to the confirmation page and you should see them populate

Comment: when `$_POST['submit']` is present you redirect to form.php. Nothing of the code below that command will be executed. But you also have a second check for that same submit a bit further down. I don't think your code will ever reach that part in submit state.

Answer (score 0):

Few comments for this code...
First, if you use:

```
header("Location:form.php");
```

You actually redirect the navigation to the file "form.php" on the same path than your main code. Two different way:

1 - Don't redirect to "form.php" by removing:

```
 <?php 

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      header("Location: form.php");
   }

 ?>
```

and just test if your data are set and do the job, don't change the location.

```
if (    !empty($_POST['submit'])
&&      !empty($_POST['postalAddress'])
&&       ...
&&      !empty($_POST['sendMethod']) ) {

      // Use data        

else {

      // Show form
}
```

2 - You can actually use a file called form.php but directly with your html form:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
     ...
</form>
```

And so, just get your code for "form.php", with some changes:

```
<?php

    /*  You have to valide all your inputs
     *  And use empty instead of isset
     *  it tests for undifined (like isset), null value
     *  and if it's empty 
     */

    if (    empty($_POST['submit'])
    ||      empty($_POST['postalAddress'])
    ||       ...
    ||      empty($_POST['sendMethod']) ) {

        // There is no (valid) form
        header("Location: yourMainCode.php");

    else {

        $forename   = $_POST['forename']; 
        $surname    = $_POST['surname'];
        $address    = $_POST['postalAddress'];
        $mobile     = $_POST['mobileTelNo'];
        $landline   = $_POST['landLineTelNo'];
        $email      = $_POST['email'];
        $sendMethod = $_POST['sendMethod'];

        // Database stuff...        

        // Redirect to a result page or something
        header("Location:result.php");

    }
?>
```

Hope it helps !